# _route parameter from Request is null with a custom operation

Tags: api-platform.com

In my Event plugged on `KernelEvents::RESPONSE => EventPriorities::PRE_READ` when I check the `_route` attribute in a custom operation I received null as `_route`

I'm running a SF 4.2.7 and api-platform/core 2.3.4 and api-platform/api-pack 1.1.0

There is my entity annotation for this operation

```
subresourceOperations={
 *         "validate_user"={
 *             "path"="/legal_documents/{id}/validate",
 *             "method"="PUT",
 *             "controller"=LegalDocumentValidate::class
 *         }
 *     }
```

And there's the Controller annotation

```
@Route(
     *     name="api_legal_documents_validate_user",
     *     path="/legal_documents/{id}/validate",
     *     methods={"PUT"},
     *     defaults={
     *          "_api_resource_class"=LegalDocument::class,
     *          "_api_item_operation_name"="validate_user"
     *     }
     * )
```

In my EventSubscriber when I dump the _route parameter I have null and a second dump with the good value, it's only with the custom operations, if I try on a operation handle by api-platform I have only 1 dump which shows the good value

Answer (score 0):

It was caused by an exception triggered before the event who was dumping the _route attribute

When you're in a Exception Event the route appears to be `null`